# Too many re-renders useState React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display objects from the array one by one by clicking on the card.

To do this, I made a check for array length (props.tasks.length), and if it is more than 1, then the array is shuffled and then I want to display these objects one by one on click.

But after a click, a new array is generated each time and often the objects are repeated 2-4 times.

But I get an error: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
function App(props) {
  let [random, setRandom] = useState({});
  let [newArr, setNewArr] = useState(props.tasks.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));
  let i = 0;
  random = newArr[i]
  setRandom(newArr[i])

  const randomCard =()=> {
    console.log(random);
    console.log(i); 
    console.log(newArr[0],newArr[1],newArr[2],newArr[3], newArr[4], newArr[5]);
    console.log(newArr[i]); 
    if (i <= newArr.length) {
      i++
    } else {
      newArr = props.tasks.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      console.log('clean');
      i=0
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {newArr.length > 1 ? (
        <div className="item" onClick={randomCard}>
          <p>{random.name}</p>
          <p>{random.translate}</p>
          <p>{random.note}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Nothing</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're trying to do in this code. You've got way more state variables than you seem to need, and are overwriting `random` for some reason. But the most fundamental flaw is that you're setting state while rendering, with your `setRandom(newArr[i]))` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main culprit in your code example is

```
setRandom(newArr[i])
```

Using a hook's set method should only be done via an action or wrapped in a `useEffect` for side effects. In your code, `setNewArr` is called on every rerender and will cause the component to rerender... causing the infinite loop of rerenders.

You also don't need to store the selected element from your array in a state,  you're essentially doing this by just storying the index in the use state.

Your solution should look something like this.

Also you want to reset `i` when it's `< newArr` and not `<= newArr` because if your array is of length "2" and i is "2" then you're setting i to "3" which doesn't point to any element in your list.

```
const shuffle = (arr) => arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

function App(props) {

  // Default empty list
  const [newArr, setNewArr] = useState([]);

  // Sets the default index to 0
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);

  // We don't want to call shuffle on every rerender, so only setNewArr
  // Once when the component is mounted.
  useEffect(() => {
   setNewArr(shuffle(props.tasks));
  }, []);

  const randomCard =()=> {
    if (i < newArr.length) {
      setI(i + 1);
    } else {
      setNewArr(shuffle(props.tasks));
      setI(0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {newArr.length > 1 ? (
        <div className="item" onClick={randomCard}>
          <p>{newArr[i].name}</p>
          <p>{newArr[i].translate}</p>
          <p>{newArr[i].note}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Nothing</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```